# Why C# cannot cast implicitly an Action<T> Where T : BaseType to Action<BaseType>

Tags: generics, casting, delegates, action

I try to cast an Action to is constraint type. Why C# cannot cast It ?

If I force cast the return is null

```
private Action<BaseObject> MyAction { get; set; }

//Cannot implicitly cast
internal void SetMyAction<TModel>(Action<TModel> action) where TModel : BaseObject
{
    MyAction = action;
}

//MyAction return null
internal void SetMyAction<TModel>(Action<TModel> action) where TModel : BaseObject
{
    MyAction = (Action<TModel>)action;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every `Action<TModel>` is an `Action<BaseObject>`. Let's look at a concrete example: `Action<string>` and `Action<object>`.

An `Action<object>` delegate can take *any* `object` reference as a parameter. It's perfectly valid to write `action(new object())`.

Now think about an `Action<string>` - it can *only* take a `string` reference. You apparently expect the following code to compile - how would you expect it to behave at execution time?

```
Action<string> printLength = text => Console.WriteLine(text.Length);
Action<object> action = printLength; // This isn't actually valid
action(new object());
```

Basically, `Action<T>` is *contravariant* in `T`, not *covariant*. So there *is* an implicit conversion from `Action<object>` to `Action<string>`, but not vice versa.

Applying that to your specific case, imagine that I had:

```
Action<DerivedObject1> x = do1 => Console.WriteLine(do1.SomeProperty);
SetMyAction<DerivedObject1>(x);

// Presumably there's *something* to invoke the action...
InvokeMyAction(new DerivedObject2());
```

What would you expect to happen?